# Custom Control Text Missing

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls

I have a custom control which is supposed to represent a label, but with rounded corners. I've created the control so it is drag and drop from the Designer Toolbox, rounded the top corners, but the Text seems to dissapear.

I know I can add another custom Property for the Text which will show at the bottom, but the Text Property is already there and ideally I would like to use it. I thought I could do it using an Override Property, but at the minute it still doesn't show.

Any suggestions, I've copied my code below...

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Design
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class CustomControl
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
    Private m_Radius As Integer
    Private m_BorderWidth As Integer
    Private m_FillColor As Color
    Private m_Text As String = Me.Text
    Private m_Label As Label

    Private components As System.ComponentModel.Container = Nothing

    Public Sub New()

        MyBase.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
    End Sub


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates a Radius of the control's corners
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>The corner Radius.</returns>
    Public Property Radius As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Radius
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_Radius = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates the width to draw the outer border of the control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>The border width.</returns>
    Public Property BorderWidth As Integer
        Get
            Return m_BorderWidth
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_BorderWidth = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates the outline colour of the control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>The outline colour.</returns>
    Public Property FillColor As Color
        Get
            Return m_FillColor
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            m_FillColor = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Browsable(True), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)> _
    Overrides Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return m_Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Text = value
            'This line just for update
            'the UI when I design to check
            'if the values are saved.
            MyBase.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Protected Overrides Sub onPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim rect As Rectangle = Me.ClientRectangle 'Drawing Rounded Rectangle
        rect.X = rect.X + 1
        rect.Y = rect.Y + 1
        rect.Width -= 2
        rect.Height -= 2

        Using bb As GraphicsPath = GetPath(rect, Radius)
            'Draw the background
            Using br As Brush = New SolidBrush(FillColor)
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear
                e.Graphics.FillPath(br, bb)
            End Using
            'Draw the border
            Using br As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
                rect.Inflate(-1, -1)
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(New Pen(br, BorderWidth), bb)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Protected Function GetPath(ByVal rc As Rectangle, ByVal r As Int32) As GraphicsPath
        Dim x As Int32 = rc.X, y As Int32 = rc.Y, w As Int32 = rc.Width - 1, h As Int32 = rc.Height - 1
        r = r << 1
        Dim path As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath()
        If r > 0 Then
            If (r > h) Then r = h
            If (r > w) Then r = w

            ' Top Left
            path.AddArc(x, y, r, r, 180, 90)

            ' Top Right
            path.AddArc(x + w - r, y, r, r, 270, 90)

            'Bottom Right
            'path.AddArc(x + w - r, y + h - r, r, r, 0, 90)
            path.AddLine(x + w, y + h, x + w, y + h)

            ' Bottom Left
            ' path.AddArc(x, y + h - r, r, r, 90, 90)
            path.AddLine(x, y + h, x, y + h)

            path.CloseFigure()
        Else
            path.AddRectangle(rc)
        End If
        Return path
    End Function

End Class
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesnt look like you are drawing the text.

Comment: @Plutonix, I knew it would be you who replied! Always on the case :). I did have the text drawing before, but underneath the painted rectangle with rounded corners. After playing around a bit, I seem to have lost the text all together :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only drawing the borders in the `OnPaint` override and not the text.  At the bottom add:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, m_Text, Me.Font, 
                     New Point(3, 3), Me.ForeColor)
```

This draws to the fixed point 3,3, but you may want to add code to calculate the location based on a `TextAlign` property (ToDo) or at least based on the `Padding` values.

If you want it to redraw the text at design time when you change it, you'll also have to add `Me.Invalidate()` to the `Text` property setter.

Comment: Thank you! That works a charm, but it would be amazing if you happened to have some spare code around which catered for the Text Align. :)

Comment: If it answers the question, please click the checkmark and upvote it.  "Chaining" questions is not well received here because it hides content.  Someone else looking for TextAlign answers isnt going to think to search for rounded user controls for the answer.  Just ask another question.

Comment: Good point. Thank you, question answered greatly plus I've managed to work around it and code for it :o)

Comment: Depending on how sophisticated it is, `Padding` can be enough